# iAd is not positioned correctly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, iad

I'm working on a game in SpriteKit and I want to implement iAd. After my app starts, the banner looks fine except it covers my view, as seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/gghwb.png

After I change the orientation of my iPhone to landscape, banner disappears. It appears again when I change the orientation back to portrait but it's position is shifted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9ukN.png

From this time the banner is visible after the orientation is changed to landscape but is also shifted.

Here's my code from UIViewController:

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
adBanner = ADBannerView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
adBanner.delegate = self
adBanner.hidden = true
adBanner.frame.origin = CGPointMake(0.0, self.view.bounds.size.height - adBanner.frame.size.height)
self.view.addSubview(adBanner)
```

What's really weird is that this position shifting happens ONLY on my iPhone. Tested it in simulator - no problems. Buddy tested on his iPhone - no problems. Covering the view at the beginning still happened though.

What's going on? I'm out of ideas. For the past few hours I tried to find it on Google with no success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, are you using Auto Layout in your view? If so, you want to place your adBanner using auto layout constraints and not by simply setting it's frame.

Comment: With regards to it overlapping, you are placing it over the top of the existing view. To prevent it overlapping, you need to reduce the height of the view by the height of the banner, and then place the banner at the bottom of the view.

Comment: Oh. My. God. Why haven't I tried this earlier? After placing the iAd banner using storyboard and connecting to the code with IBOutlet, everything works correctly. Thank you!!! BTW I still dont get it why the problem showed up only on my phone... Weird...

Answer (score 0):

iOS 9.2.1, Xcode 7.2.1, ARC enabled

*Check your Developer Settings for iAd in Settings for your iPhone.*

From my experience the issue is with `self.canDisplayBannerAds = true` and then changing the frame of adBanner without massaging it properly, this is where you run into trouble.

In all of the Apple examples, they never set this property, you can see for yourself:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iAdSuite_Storyboard/Listings/BasicBanner_BasicBanner_TextViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013458-BasicBanner_BasicBanner_TextViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6

I ran into this when animating an adBanner to raise once an ad is loaded, or something similar to this behavior.  I think it has a lot to do with this...

> To ensure that advertisements are displayed properly, a banner view
>   must always be sized to match one of the built-in advertising sizes.
>   ***The ADBannerView class enforces this by preventing you from changing
>   the frame directly. Instead, you change a banner view’s frame by
>   setting the currentContentSizeIdentifier property.*** Changing the value
>   stored in this property resizes the banner view’s frame to the match
>   the size for the provided identifier. Before you can set a particular
>   size identifier, the size identifier must also be included in the set
>   of size identifiers included in the requiredContentSizeIdentifiers
>   property.

The rest of this document is here, if you are curious:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/BannerAdvertisements/BannerAdvertisements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH3-SW2

From the Apple "Basic Banner" example I linked in the beginning, they play around with the banner frame by first accessing the `sizeThatFits` property of the ad banner:

```
// all we need to do is ask the banner for a size that fits into the layout area we are using
CGSize sizeForBanner = [self.bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];
```

Once the `self.canDisplayBannerAds` is set, the following happens:

*Taken from UIViewController(iAdAdditions)*

> ...When a view controller enables banner ads, the system puts the view
>   controller’s content view inside of a new content view that the system
>   manages. This allows the system to dynamically resize the original
>   content view when a banner ad is displayed, as well as managing the
>   display of the banner ad itself. This property provides access to the
>   original content view, rather than the containing view that manages
>   banner ad display.
>
> If banner ad display has not been enabled for a view controller, this
>   property returns the content view.
>
> If banner ad display is enabled and then later disabled for a view
>   controller, the system-managed content view is not removed.

Hope this helps.  Cheers!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply but not sure if you noticed - I posted this question over a year ago :) Right now not dealing with ads, but if I will have this problem again I will know where to look!

Comment: Yeah I did, I was looking for some answers to this myself, ended up spending a few days trying different solutions, decided to post my findings here to save others time.  Great question!  Hope you find my answer at least interesting.